# Is a statement recalculated in every iteration when used in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

For instance

```
myEnumerable.Where(v => v != myDictionary["someKey"])
```

when this query is called is `myDictionary["someKey"]` statement executed (meaning that dictionary is queried for the key) or the result of `myDictionary["someKey"]`
is used after the first iteration?

Comment: You could probably test that yourself and answer your own question

Comment: @MattBurland I actually did. But I don't know why but profilers I used gave unstable results. One trial was better than other. I couldn't make a generalization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `myDictionary["someKey"]` will not be cached<sup>(*see edit below)</sup>, it will be accessed on every item of `myEnumerable`. However, you can still cache it manually :

```
var someValue = myDictionary["someKey"];
myEnumerable.Where(v => v != someValue)
```

Also take note that, if you plan to iterate/access that `IEnumerable` multiple time, it is best to actualize it via `ToList()`. Or, the execution will be deferred every single time.

```
var query = myEnumerable.Where(v => v != myDictionary["someKey"]);

foreach (var item in query) { /* ... */}
foreach (var item in query) { /* ... */}
```

In the above example, the `Where` clause is executed twice.

---

EDIT: As @LucasTrzesniewski has pointed out, this is only stands true for `LINQ-to-Objects`. This is because the query is evaluated in memory. However, for `LINQ-to-Entities`, it gets a little bit different, as the query will be converted into SQL query and then executed in the database in order to avoid round trips.

Comment: I will accept it in 9 minutes. By the way, it is sure right?

Comment: this is correct. the lambda creates a closure over the dictionary, it doesn't "save" a copy of the value in a local variable.

Comment: Note that in LINQ-to-SQL, `myDictionary["someKey"]` would actually be evaluated only once, and its value would be sent to the DB as a parameter of the query. This answer is correct for LINQ-to-Objects though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple demo (and please, don't try this at home):

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>() { { "someKey", "someValue" } };
var myEnumerable = new List<string> { "someValue", "someOtherValue" };

var test = myEnumerable.Where(v => v == myDictionary["someKey"]);

foreach (var t in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    myDictionary["someKey"] = "someOtherValue";
}
```

If `myDictionary["someKey"]` was only evaulated once, then changing the value of `myDictionary["someKey"]` wouldn't change anything. But if you run the code, you will see that it will echo both `someValue` and `someOtherValue`. If you comment out the line that changes the dictionary value, then you will only see `someValue`

As @Lucas Trzesniewski points out in the comments to the other answer, this applies to LINQ-to-objects. There are a number of important differences between LINQ-to-objects and LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: I can't blame myself for not coming up with this idea. This is kind of a genius one.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda expression you supply to the Linq `Where` extension is simply a Func<> delegate.  The method is executed for each item in the IEnumerable(of T), receiving the current item as a parameter.  It doesn't do anything special other than that.  Your code is somewhat similar similar to:

```
var myTempCollection = new List<MyClass>();

foreach(MyClass item in myEnumerable)
{
   if (item != myDictionary["someKey"])
   {
        myTempCollection.Add(item);
    }
}

var result = myTempCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the QueryProvider implementation. For example, the ObjectQueryProvider used by Linq-to-objects will access it on every iteration. For Linq-to-entities, it will access it once and then send that value to the database server.